# Вывод данных из MySQL

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Подскажите, как вывести данные из базы, чтоб получить вот такое меню?

[image]

Как вывести основные пункты меню, я знаю, но как выводить подпункты этого меню, нет. (
Подскажите, кто знает! Вот мой код. Заранее спасибо.

```
<?php
$result_dop_cat = mysql_query ("SELECT id,title,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dop_dan WHERE 
dop_dan.cat=dop_cat.id) AS kol  FROM dop_cat",$db);

if (!$result_dop_cat)
{   
    echo "<p>Запрос на выбор данных не прошел! Прозьба сообщить об этом 
    администратору сайта<br><strong>Код ошибки:</strong></p>";

    exit (mysql_error());   
}
if (mysql_num_rows ($result_dop_cat) > 0)
{
    $myrow_dop_cat = mysql_fetch_array ($result_dop_cat);

    do {
        printf ("<a class='menu' href='view_dopmat.php?cat=%s'>%s
        (%s)</a>",$myrow_dop_cat['id'],$myrow_dop_cat['title'],$myrow_dop_cat['kol']);
    }
    while ($myrow_dop_cat = mysql_fetch_array ($result_dop_cat));
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласен, что надо прописать parent_id. Но вывод я бы организовал таким образом:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($DB))
    $rows[] = $row;

function genStruct($ar, $id = 0, $level = 1)
{
    $il = sizeof($ar);
    $s = '<ul class="level'.$level.'">';
    for($i = 0; $i < $il; ++$i)
        if($ar[$i]['parent_id'] == $id)
            $s .= '<li>'.if($ar[$i]['title'].genStruct($ar, $ar[$i]['id'], $level+1).'</li>';
    $s .= '</ul>';
    return $s;
}

echo genStruct($rows);
```

Этот способ предусматривает любой уровень вложенности, но может тормозить при большом количестве элементов.

Answer (score 0):

[Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html).

Comment: Спасибо! Буду переводить. )

Answer (score 0):

Не бросайте переводить.

Но если горит, то можете сделать грубо:
Создайте в таблице `dop_cat` еще одно поле, допустим `id_parent_cat`, в него записывайте уникальный id соответствующего родительского пункта.

При выборке из БД можно действовать примерно так (не проверял):

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($DB))
{
    $row['html']='<li>'.$row['title'].'</li>';
    $parent[$row['parent_id']]=$row;
}

foreach ($parent[0] as $row)
{
    $arr[] = '
    <li>
        '.$row['title'].'
        <ul>
            '.implode('',$parent[$row['parent_id']]['html']).'
        </ul>
    </li>';
}

echo '<ul>'.implode('',$arr).'</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

А я пользуюсь такой функцией:
(родительский элемент, текст, префикс перед дочерним элементом)

```
function get_category_by_pid($parent, $text, $prefix = '&nbsp;&#9658;&nbsp;'){  
    global $DB;  
    $q = "SELECT `id`, `parent`, `name` FROM `ps42_category` WHERE `id`=".$parent." AND `id`<>0";  
    $res = $DB->fetch($q);  
    if(!empty($res)){  
        $text = $prefix.'    <span><a style="color: #57626e; font-size: 12px;" href="index.php?module=catalog&category='.$res[0]['id'].'">'.$res[0]['name'].'</a></span>'.$text;  
        return get_category_by_pid($res[0]['parent'], $text);  
    }  
    return $text;  
}
```

Пардон, не догоняю, как правильно отформатировать. Переменная $text накапливается. Внутри просто вывод в удобной для вас форме.

Comment: @kemerov4anin Чтобы отформатировать код, нужно выделить код мышкой и нажать на кнопку 101010 или просто добавить четыре пробела перед каждой строкой кода.